# Making captcha image in PHP

Tags: php, gd, captcha

I'm trying to use the GD graphics library to make this captcha image, and the box shows up how Id like it to, but the text isn't being displayed over the image at all.  I can't figure out why it's not showing up.

```
<?php
session_start();
putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.') );
$font = 'Molle';
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(260, 40);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255,255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 215, 215, 215);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 3, 3, 255, 34, $grey);
$text = 'Testing';
$_SESSION["captcha"] = $text;
imagettftext( $im, 20, 0, 16, 26, $white, $font, $text );
imagettftext( $im, 20, 0, 15, 25, $black, $font, $text );
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: you need to put header() much lower in the code, to be able to see error messages.

Comment: You need to do trouble-shooting if the information you have at hand only puzzles you. That normally shows you the answer then. Use a step-debugger to look inside your code. Also please check your formattings, I showed you how you can use many lines of code - however your code has these > at the beginning of each line, you might want do change that.

Comment: The whole point of a captcha is that it is easy to read for humans but hard for computers. Writing a word in a straight line, even if in a weird font and in two colors can be circumvented by an advanced bot, not to mention the peasants on Mechanical Turk. If you need a captcha, you're better off using [reCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) - at least the results would do something good and its much better from a usability viewpoint. Plus, by definition, it has the words that the best computers in the world cannot recognize.